# My concept for template class hiding breaks data member inheritance. Why?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to add support for protobuf events to my existing event queue.

I wrote a proof-of-concept (see below), which seemed to work fine at first. Unfortunately, compilation aborts when accessing inherited data members. Accessing inherited function members works just fine. Following classes are declared:

- Abstract class `SubscriptionHolderBase`: This is the interface base class
- Abstract class `SubscriptionHolderCommon`: Is supposed to hold the common members of the following two classes.
- Depending on the type of the event to subscribe, the compiler shall automatically choose one of the following classes to instantiate:

  - Template class `SubscriptionHolder`, specialized for *normal* events.
  - Templace class `SubscriptionHolder`, spezialized for all other (i.e. *protobuf*) events.

For some reason, `SubscriptionHolder` seems to inherit the function member of `SubscriptionHolderCommon` just fine, but when trying to access the data member `_member_var` (inherited from the same class), following error message is produced:

```
error: ‘_member_var’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can someone explain the reason?

### My proof-of-concept code:

When commenting all 3 occurences of `_member_var`, it is doing just fine.
[You can compile and let it run online here.](http://cpp.sh/7yt4r)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class ProtobufEvent {
};

class Proto2 : public ProtobufEvent {
};

class Event {
    public:
        virtual ~Event(){};
};

class SubscriptionHolderBase {
    public: 
        virtual bool dispatch(Event* event) = 0;
        virtual void handle() = 0;
};

template<typename EventType>
class SubscriptionHolderCommon : public SubscriptionHolderBase {
    public:
        void handle() {
            std::cout << "Member function of unspecialized common base class called." << std::endl;
        }

    protected:
        bool _member_var;
};

template<typename EventType, typename Enable = void>
class SubscriptionHolder;

template<typename EventType> 
class SubscriptionHolder<EventType, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<EventType*, ProtobufEvent*>::value>::type> : public SubscriptionHolderCommon<EventType> {
    public:
        virtual bool dispatch(Event* event);
};

template<typename EventType>
class SubscriptionHolder<EventType, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<EventType*, ProtobufEvent*>::value>::type>  : public SubscriptionHolderCommon<EventType> {
    public:
        virtual bool dispatch(Event* event);
};

template<typename EventType>
bool SubscriptionHolder<EventType, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<EventType*, ProtobufEvent*>::value>::type>::dispatch(Event* event) {
    std::cout << "Member function of specialized class for protobuf event called." << std::endl;
    _member_var = true;
        return false;
}

template<typename EventType>
bool SubscriptionHolder<EventType, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<EventType*, ProtobufEvent*>::value>::type>::dispatch(Event* event) {
    std::cout << "Member function of specialized class for standard event called." << std::endl;
    _member_var = true;
    return false;
}



int main() {
    Event* e = nullptr;
    SubscriptionHolderBase* ptr;

    SubscriptionHolder<Event> s_e;
    ptr = &s_e;
    ptr->handle();
    ptr->dispatch(e);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    SubscriptionHolder<ProtobufEvent> s_p;
    ptr = &s_p;
    ptr->handle();
    ptr->dispatch(e);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    SubscriptionHolder<Proto2> s_p2;
    ptr = &s_p2;
    ptr->handle();
    ptr->dispatch(e);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is because when your base is a template, you have to explicitly tell the compiler you wasn't to use base members / functions. For a data member preceding it with this-> should work. That said, your design seems rather more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: ` this->_member_var = true;` - but this design stinks

Comment: @NirFriedman Thanks for your response, but I don't yet get it. `_member_var` *is* a base member, so why should I tell it not to use base members? (Or was it just a typo and you meant it the other way round?) Also, how what's the technical reason that preceding it with `this->` helps? I'm very interested in suggestions how to make the code simpler/better. Suggestions are welcome. I'm totally beyond my knowledge level here. Thanks!

Comment: @Multisync Basically, when the base class is a template, the derived type will not know which base it is inheriting from until instantiation. So if you think about it, any name that you write whatsoever (even a call to a free function), could actually happen to be in the base, or at least one particular specialized base. To prevent this craziness, things defined in the base (functions and variables) are simply excluded from unqualified lookup. Preceding with this does not mean "this class", it means "this object" which includes the base class.

Comment: As for your design, I'm not sure that SO is really the right venue for a longer discussion but basically: it's not clear at all why the common class has to be templated at all. You don't use the template parameter for anything. It's not clear why you are using a single derived template class with enable_if shenanigans. You could just have two template classes, one for each case (and maybe a static_assert). Or you could even have two concrete classes; it's hard to say without knowing more about how the events are structured. There's just a lot of complexity here and it's probably not necessary.